# How to convert query string to url names

Tags: url-rewriting

My url is   ..../blogs?id=1&title=news

Now i need to covert this to

```
..../blogs/1/news
```

in .htaccess.

Please how to convert this. help me.

Answer (score 1):

Use these lines:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^blogs/(.+)/(.+)$ /blogs.php?id=$1&title=$2 [R,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Comment: error occured when i access in the browser like  http://localhost/project1/blogs/1/news

Comment: Maybe I understood the contrary. do you want `?id-=&title=` to ` /1/2` or `/1/2` to query string?

Comment: Url should be /blogs/1/2.  But in the code i can get 1 as id and 2 as title.

Comment: It is easier. I've changed my answer

Comment: /1/2 to query string.

Comment: Very very thanks  splash58. if same concept reverse means, how it will be?

Comment: URL should not change(/blogs/1/2). but i can get id and title values from my code.       Is it possible?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want.

Comment: Actually my file name in blogs.php. early i was calling blogs.php?id=1. Now i want to call blogs/1/title. if i use above command it throws "object not found error".

Comment: Try now. i add .php extention